# assigning a position to each item in a list checking if one already exists

Tags: c#, linq, loops

I have a list of "Boxes". there is a value called "position" against each box in the list.

When my list of boxes is built, some are given a position (int) . Position is a value used by my code to determine where each box fits on my page.

So, I have a list with 13 boxes, I have one box with position =13 and one with position 4. the rest are currently null.

There is another field called "order" against a box. What I need to do now is order everything  that doesn't have a "position" value by the value in "order". (order is not nullable).

Easy so far. However, what I now need to do is loop each value returned and give them a position value. BUT I need to skip over the position values that are already taken (currently 4 and 13).

This is what I am doing:

```
                var orderedBoxes = (from a in boxes
                                    orderby a.Order
                                    where a.Position == null
                                    select a).ToList();

                List<int> takenPositions = (from a in boxes
                                      where a.Position != null
                                      select a.Position).ToList();


                foreach (var box in orderedBoxes)
                {

                    if (takenPositions.Contains(i))
                    {
                        //    i++
                        //    box.Position =i;
                    }
                    //box.Position =i;
                }
```

i thought this might be ok, but upon reflection, what if takenPositions Does contains i and the value after i++ is also in takenPositions?

I feel I need some form of loop here to test the result of i++ after each increment.

Can anyone offer any help please!!

Comment: I'm confused, what is type `Position`?  It it `int` ? if so `orderedBoxes` will be always empty! Remember `int` can never be `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be solved if you'd change

```
    if (takenPositions.Contains(i))
```

in

```
    while (takenPositions.Contains(i))
```

It automatically increments until it finds a free position.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use the good old for loop:

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= boxes.Count; i++)
{
    if (takenPositions.Contains(i)) continue;
    orderedBoxes[j++].Position = i;
}
```